# Xcode - Scaling image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to scale an image but remain the aspect ratio.
I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
[_malmohusEtt setClipsToBounds:YES];
[_malmohusTva setClipsToBounds:YES];
[_malmohusEtt setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[_malmohusTva setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Please help me

Comment: what is the type of `_malmohusEtt` ? `UIImageView` ? `UIView` ?

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *malmohusEtt;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *malmohusTva; `

@Raptor

Comment: Because when I rotate, it rotates but it's in the center of the view and not fitting to the edges.

Comment: I think you didn't apply Auto Layout constraints.

Comment: @Raptor , how do I do that then? :P 
Because I've tried with and without missing constraints.

Comment: I think your constraints do not work with landscape orientation. Did you set fixed width in your `UIImageView`? If yes, you'd better use other constraint types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an sample code to scale image to any size maintaining aspect ratio programatically.

```
- (UIImage*) scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGSize scaledSize = newSize;
    float scaleFactor = 1.0;
    if( image.size.width > image.size.height ) {
        scaleFactor = image.size.width / image.size.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height / scaleFactor;
    }
    else if(image.size.height > image.size.width) {
        scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width / scaleFactor;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( scaledSize, NO, 0.0 );
    CGRect scaledImageRect = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height );
    [image drawInRect:scaledImageRect];
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage; }
```

[image]

Comment: This will also help to maintain image quality.

Comment: I get a bunch of errors, what am I doing wrong? :(
"Property 'size' not found on object of type 'Malmohus'"

Comment: I have edited the source code as per your requirement.

Comment: Please check with the updated code. Pass the UIImage instance to the function it will return scaled image as a result.

Comment: So I post all of that code under viewdidload. And do I need to add any more code??

Comment: Check the attached screenshot.

Comment: No, just don't use this approach. Extra RAM will be used to resize the image.